# How can I run a python script on windows?

Tags: python, ide

Can anyone please tell me an IDE for running python programs? Is it possible to run the program through command line?

Comment: Who is dealing out all these -1 (Q & A alike)? Would you mind to comment?

Comment: +1 to counter the unexplained downvote.

Comment: Actually, got downvoted in all of our answers, also, I am going to upvote all of the answers except myself.

Comment: The answers I could understand being downvoted - they answered the wrong question, it would appear.

Comment: @Grundleflect, There is two part in question, and Original Question included "Can anyone plz tell me an IDE for running python programs.", you can check in edit logs, Some of us are answered for IDE, at that time.

Comment: @S.Mark: fair enough, I hadn't thought of the question changing.

Comment: -1: http://www.python.org/, "Python runs on Windows" is prominently placed near the top of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ActiveState's ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/). It's quite a nice implementation of Python on Windows. Another way is using [Cygwin's Python port](http://www.cygwin.com). These two are Python *implementations*. I don't use an IDE, I write my Python code in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sf.net).

To run a python program after saving it to `C:\Users\vaibhav\Code\myscript.py`:

1. ActivePython: If I remember right, ActiveState updates the path correctly. So it should be a s simple as:

   - Press "start" in the task bar
   - In the search field search for "cmd"
   - In the appearing box navigate to your folder with the python script: `dir Users\vaibhav\Code`
   - call `python myscript.py` and you're done
2. Cygwin: After installing Cygwin, you have a full-featured bash terminal on your Windows machine.

   - click on the Cygwin icon on your desktop
   - In the appearing window navigate to the folder with your python script: `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/vaibhav/Code`
   - type `python myscript.py`
   - e voila

Comment: how do you run the program after scripting in NOTEPAD++??

Comment: What do you need cygwin for? Python works fine on windows, there is no need for that.

Comment: What do you need Windows for, if there isn't Cygwin installed?

Answer (score 3):

IDE for running scripts? You can have any IDE you like, but if you need only to run python scripts you go like this:

python.exe pythonScript.py

Comment: does'nt that require to set class path for python?

Answer (score 0):

I like the [EasyEclipse for python](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/index.html) distribution. You'd need to have python and java  installed of course.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev and Komodo Edit are 2 nice Python IDE on Windows.

I also like the SciTE text editor very much.

These 3 solutions make possible to run Python scripts

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run a Python script with multiprocessing on windows. [see this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing/5550156#5550156)

It does not work on Windows, but on raspian it went very well. Thus I knew that it was a Windows problem. I installed cygwin and followed this tutorial [Installing Python inside Cygwin](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/Installing-Python-inside-Cygwin).

After that I additionally installed numpy with the command `easy_install numpy` and now i can run python scripts with multiprocessing on windows (from cygwin).