# How to avoid copy of a non-global numpy array between process?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy, multiprocessing

I've read " [Is shared readonly data copied to different processes for Python multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing) " but the array described there is global. Is it possible to do the same with local arrays ?

Comment: if you can use Cython, you can share the array between different threads only working with the pointers, [as shown here...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20520295/832621)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so - but you can save stuff to a module variable. If you do this before the fork (and you are not on windows) it should work fine.

Eg

```
import mymodule

def somefunc(parameter):
    # do something with mymodule.var

# load/process local data
# save to module variable
mymodule.var = var
# now fork
p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
p.map(somefunc, list_of_params)
```

If you use ipython you need to put somefunc in a module too (pickling functions in **main** doesn't seem to work).

Comment: Doesn't work. Copy-on-write is invalidated by most reads due to the reference counter being incremented.

Comment: But for large variables updating the reference counter will copy just the page containing the reference counter - not the whole (untouched) data. I work usually with large numpy arrays for which the above works well.