# Parallelizing with Cython memoryviews

Tags: parallel-processing, cython

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do. I'm computing pairwise distances between matrices that I've arranged into a stacked array. The `idx` array holds the offsets of each submatrix.

When I remove the `parallel()` and replace `prange` with `range`, the code works as expected (just not in parallel, of course).

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def all_pairs_distance(float[:,::1] stacked, int[::1] idx):
  cdef int n = idx.shape[0] - 1
  cdef float[:,::1] D = np.zeros((n,n), dtype='float32')
  cdef int i,j
  cdef float[:,::1] t1,t2
  cdef float d
  with nogil, parallel():
    for i in prange(n):
      t1 = stacked[idx[i]:idx[i+1],:]
      for j in range(i+1, n):
        t2 = stacked[idx[j]:idx[j+1],:]
        d = nogil_cython_function(t1, t2)
        D[i,j] = d
        D[j,i] = d
  return D

cdef float nogil_cython_function(float[:,::1] a, float[:,::1] b) nogil:
  # Function abbreviated for simplicity
  return 0.0
```

When trying to compile this file, I get errors on each assignment to `t1` or `t2`:

```
Memoryview slices can only be shared in parallel sections
```

1. I'm not sure how to resolve this error. Are those assignments not in a parallel section?
2. How do I tell the compiler that my `stacked` memoryview is read-only, and is fine to share between threads?

Comment: I think you can give to each thread only the part of the array they will actually use. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20520295/832621) where this is achieved using raw pointers (which I find more straightforward for this task)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out, after a bit of experimenting:

```
for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
  for j in range(i+1, n):
    d = nogil_cython_function(stacked[idx[i]:idx[i+1],:],
                              stacked[idx[j]:idx[j+1],:])
```

The takeaway is that slicing memoryviews inside a `prange` is fine, but assigning those slices to variables is not.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to get prange working with memoryview slices.  Apparently not documented elsewhere is your solution, just don't assign the slice to a variable, use the slice directly.

Comment: Or "wrap" code inside the prange loop into a little helper function (just rewrite your nogil_cython_function such that it accepts stacked itself instead of the slices). Inside the helper function you can assign memoryviews however you like. At least this worked in simple test for me as of now.