# cython openmp single, barrier

Tags: openmp, cython

I'm trying to use openmp in cython. I need to do two things in cython:

i) use the `#pragma omp single{}` scope in my cython code.

ii) use the `#pragma omp barrier{}`

Does anyone know how to do this in cython?

Here are more details. I have a nogil cdef-function `my_fun()` which I call in an omp for-loop:

```
from cython.parallel cimport prange
cimport openmp

cdef int i

with nogil:
    for i in prange(10,schedule='static', num_threads=10):
        my_func(i)
```

Inside `my_func` I need to place a barrier to wait for all threads to catch up, then execute a time-consuming operation only in one of the threads and with the gil acquired, and then release the barrier so all threads resume simultaneously.

```
cdef int my_func(...) nogil:

    ...

    # put a barrier until all threads catch up, e.g. #pragma omp barrier

    with gil:
        # execute time consuming operation in one thread only, e.g. pragma omp single{}

    # remove barrier after the above single thread has finished and continue the operation over all threads in parallel, e.g. #pragma omp barrier

    ...
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520295/832621), showing how to use Cython's `prange` to get openmp to work just fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cython has some support for openmp, but it is probably easier to code in C and to wrap resulting code with Cython if openmp-pragmas are used extensively.

---

As alternative, you could use verbatim-C-code and tricks with defines to bring some of the functionality to Cython, but using of pragmas in defines isn't straight forward (`_Pragma` is a [C99-solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019), MSVC doing its own thing as always with [`__pragma`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019)), there are some examples as proof of concept for Linux/gcc:

```py
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #define START_OMP_PARALLEL_PRAGMA() _Pragma("omp parallel") {
    #define END_OMP_PRAGMA() }
    #define START_OMP_SINGLE_PRAGMA() _Pragma("omp single") {
    #define START_OMP_CRITICAL_PRAGMA() _Pragma("omp critical") {   
    """
    void START_OMP_PARALLEL_PRAGMA() nogil
    void END_OMP_PRAGMA() nogil
    void START_OMP_SINGLE_PRAGMA() nogil
    void START_OMP_CRITICAL_PRAGMA() nogil
```

we make Cython believe, that `START_OMP_PARALLEL_PRAGMA()` and Co. are nogil-function, so it put them into C-code and thus they get pick up by the preprocessor.

We must use the syntax

```c
#pragma omp single{
   //do_something
}
```

and not

```c
#pragma omp single
do_something
```

because of the way Cython generates C-code.

The usage could look as follows (I'm avoiding here `from cython.parallel.parallel` as it does too much magic for this simple example):

```py
%%cython -c=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp
cdef extern from *:# as listed above
    ...

def test_omp():
    cdef int a=0
    cdef int b=0  
    with nogil:
        START_OMP_PARALLEL_PRAGMA()
        START_OMP_SINGLE_PRAGMA()
        a+=1
        END_OMP_PRAGMA()
        START_OMP_CRITICAL_PRAGMA()
        b+=1
        END_OMP_PRAGMA() # CRITICAL
        END_OMP_PRAGMA() # PARALLEL
    print(a,b)
```

Calling `test_omp` prints "1 2" on my machine with 2 threads, as expected (one could change the number of threads using `openmp.omp_set_num_threads(10)`).

However, the above is still very brittle - some error checking by Cython can lead to invalid code (Cython uses goto for control flow and it is not possible to jump out of openmp-block). Something like this happens in your example:

```py
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
def test_omp2():
    cdef np.int_t[:] a=np.zeros(1,dtype=int)

    START_OMP_SINGLE_PRAGMA()
    a[0]+=1
    END_OMP_PRAGMA()

    print(a)
```

Because of bounding checking, Cython will produce:

```c
START_OMP_SINGLE_PRAGMA();
...
//check bounds:
if (unlikely(__pyx_t_6 != -1)) {
    __Pyx_RaiseBufferIndexError(__pyx_t_6);
    __PYX_ERR(0, 30, __pyx_L1_error)  // HERE WE GO A GOTO!
}
...
END_OMP_PRAGMA();
```

In this special case setting boundcheck to false, i.e.

```py
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) 
def test_omp2():
   ...
```

would solve the issue for the above example, but probably not in general.

Once again: using openmp in C (and wrapping the functionality with Cython) is a more enjoyable experience.

---

As a side note: Python-threads (the ones governed by GIL) and openmp-threads are different and know nothing about eachother. The above example would also work (compile and run) correctly without releasing the GIL - openmp-threads do not care about GIL, but as there are no Python-objects involved nothing can go wrong. Thus I have added `nogil` to the wrapped "functions", so it can also be used in nogil blocks.

However, when code gets more complicated it becomes less obvious, that the variables shared between different Python-threads aren't accessed (all above because those accesses could happen in the generated C-code and this doesn't become clear from the Cython-code), it might be wiser not to release gil, while using openmp.