# Is there a good way to avoid memory deep copy or to reduce time spent in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing, bigdata

I am making a memory-based real-time calculation module of "Big data" using Pandas module of the Python environment.

So response time is the quality of this module and very critical and important.

To process large data set, I split the data and process sub split data in parallel.

In the part of storing the result of sub data, much time spend(21th line).

I think that internally memory deep copy arises or sub data passed are not shared in memory.

If I written the module in C or C++, I will use pointer or reference like below.

"process=Process(target=addNewDerivedColumn, args=[resultList, **&sub_dataframe**])"

or

"process=Process(target=addNewDerivedColumn, args=[resultList, sub_dataframe])

def addNewDerivedColumn(resultList, **split_sub_dataframe&**):....
"

**Is there a good way to avoid memory deep copy or to reduce time spent in multiprocessing?**
"Not elegant" is fine. 
I am ready for making my codes dirty.
I tried weekref, RawValue, RawArray, Value, Pool but all failed.

The module is being developed in MacOS and finally is going to run in Linux or Unix.

Do not consider Windows OS.

Here comes the code.

The real code is in my office but the structure and logic are the same as the real one.

```
1 #-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-' 
2 import pandas as pd
3 import numpy as np
4 from multiprocessing import *
5 import time
6
7
8 def addNewDerivedColumn(resultList, split_sub_dataframe):
9    
10    split_sub_dataframe['new_column']=    np.abs(split_sub_dataframe['column_01']+split_sub_dataframe['column_01']) / 2
11    
12    print split_sub_dataframe.head()
13    
14    '''
15     i think that the hole result of sub-dataframe is copied to resultList, not reference value 
16     and in here time spend much
17     compare elapsed time of comment 21th line with the uncommented one
18     In MS Windows, signifiant difference of elapsed time doesn't show up
19     In Linux or Mac OS, the difference is big
20    '''
21    resultList.append(split_sub_dataframe)
22    
23
24
25 if __name__ == "__main__":
26    
27    # example data generation
28    # the record count of the real data is over 1 billion with about 10 columns.
29    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000000, 4), columns=['column_01', 'column_02', 'column_03', 'column_04'])
30    
31
32    print 'start...'
33    start_time = time.time()
34    
35    # to launch 5 process in parallel, I split the dataframe to five sub-dataframes
36    split_dataframe_list = np.array_split(dataframe, 5)
37    
38    # multiprocessing 
39    manager = Manager()
40    
41    # result list
42    resultList=manager.list()
43    processList=[]
44    
45    for sub_dataframe in split_dataframe_list:
46        process=Process(target=addNewDerivedColumn, args=[resultList, sub_dataframe])
47        processList.append(process)
48        
49    for proc in processList: 
50        proc.start()
51    for proc in processList: 
52        proc.join()
53    
54    
55    print 'elapsed time  : ', np.round(time.time() - start_time,3)
```

Comment: If you can use raw arrays where you can extract the ctypes pointer (e.g. numpy arrays), that can be shared without a copy. See this answer for some details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5550156/1079728. But I don't think it's possible with regular python objects.

Comment: Note that multiprocessing simply uses `pickle` to serialize objects and pass them around. The `Manager` class spawns a new process whose memory is used to keep the shared objects, but you still *have* to transfer the objects there. Also, the operations in your `AddNewDerivedColumn` seem quite simply, so you'd better use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of manually creating `Process`es by hand. Probably using `Pool.map` you could avoid creating the shared `list` completely which should be a quite big gain in speed.

Comment: @Robert McGibbon I read and tried before the link you commented. but I failed unfortunately.

Comment: @Bakuriu I am using Windows in my house. Now `Pool` works in unusual way in Windows. Tomorrow I will go to the office and try `Pool.map` as you advised.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will get better performance if you keep interprocess communication to a
minimum. Therefore, instead of passing sub-DataFrames as arguments, just pass
index values. The subprocess can slice the common DataFrame itself.

When a subprocess is spawned, it gets a copy of all the globals defined in the
calling module of the parent process. Thus, if the large DataFrame, `df`, is
defined in the globals *before* you spawn a multiprocessing pool, then each
spawned subprocess will have access to `df`.

On Windows, where there is no `fork()`, a new python process is started and the
calling module is imported. Thus, on Windows, the spawned subprocess has to
regenerate `df` from scratch, which could take time and much additional memory.

On Linux, however, you have copy-on-write. This means that the spawned
subprocess accesses the original globals (of the calling module) *without
copying* them. Only when the subprocess tries to modify the global does Linux
then make a separate copy before the value is modified.

So you can enjoy a performance gain if you avoid modifying globals in your
subprocesses.  I suggest using the subprocess only for computation. Return the
value of the computation, and let the main process collate the results to modify
the original DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def compute(start, end):
    sub = df.iloc[start:end]
    return start, end, np.abs(sub['column_01']+sub['column_01']) / 2

def collate(retval):
    start, end, arr = retval
    df.ix[start:end, 'new_column'] = arr

def window(seq, n=2):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the sequence
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...
    """
    for i in range(len(seq)-n+1):
        yield tuple(seq[i:i+n])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = []
    # the record count of the real data is over 1 billion with about 10 columns.
    N = 10**3
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N, 4),
                      columns=['column_01', 'column_02', 'column_03', 'column_04'])

    pool = mp.Pool()    
    df['new_column'] = np.empty(N, dtype='float')

    start_time = time.time()
    idx = np.linspace(0, N, 5+1).astype('int')
    for start, end in window(idx, 2):
        # print(start, end)
        pool.apply_async(compute, args=[start, end], callback=collate)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print 'elapsed time  : ', np.round(time.time() - start_time,3)
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try your approach and additional comment to you. It will be very helpful for those who are going to program large-sized datas in parallel way with the DataFrame of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this question and @unutbu's answer, I wrote a parallel-version of map at [github](https://github.com/fashandge/partools). The function is suitable for infinitely parallelizable processing of a *read-only* large data structure in a single machine with multiple cores. The basic idea is similar to @unutbu sugggested, using a temporary global variable to hold the big data structure (e.g., a data frame), and pass its "name" rather than the variable itself to workers. But all of this are encapsulated in a map function so that it is almost a drop-in replacement of the standard map function, with the help of pathos package. The example usage is as follows,

```
# Suppose we process a big dataframe with millions of rows.
size = 10**9
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(size, 4),
                  columns=['column_01', 'column_02', 
                           'column_03', 'column_04'])
# divide df into sections of 10000 rows; each section will be
# processed by one worker at a time
section_size = 10000
sections = [xrange(start, start+section_size) 
            for start in xrange(0, size, section_size)]

# The worker function that processes one section of the
# df. The key assumption is that a child 
# process does NOT modify the dataframe, but do some 
# analysis or aggregation and return some result.
def func(section, df):
    return some_processing(df.iloc[section])

num_cores = 4
# sections (local_args) specify which parts of a big object to be processed;
# global_arg holds the big object to be processed to avoid unnecessary copy;
# results are a list of objects each of which is the processing results 
# of one part of a big object (i.e., one element in the iterable sections) 
# in order.
results = map(func, sections, global_arg=df,
              chunksize=10, 
              processes=num_cores)

# reduce results (assume it is a list of data frames)
result = pd.concat(results)
```

In some of my text mining tasks, naive parallel implementation that passes df directly to the worker function is even slower than the single-threaded version, due to expensive copy operation of large data frame. However, the above implementation can give >3 times speedup for those tasks with 4 cores, which seems pretty close to real light-weight multi-threading.