# Vectorizing a Multi-Dimensional Function in Python

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy, vectorization

I have been a frequent lurker on Stack Overflow for some time and I tend to find very useful and clear information from here whenever I have coding questions. However, I can't really seem to find a thread that addresses my specific inquiry today.

Earlier today, I learned about vectorizing functions in Python in order to speed up computing time. I am currently trying to optimize a python program that I had written a little over a month ago. My program takes a text file containing data in the following format:

`<magnitude> <dmagnitude> <exposure_number>`

I then assign each column to lists `mag`, `dmag`, and `expnum`.

What I want to do is create a 2d array of the `mag` and `dmag` values that share the same `expnum` (having the same exposure number means that the `mag` and `dmag` point to the same data point).

I do this for all exposure numbers and, at the end, I take the median of the `mag` and `dmag`, and the standard deviation of the `mag` for each of the exposure number-based arrays and combine them all into one array that I can plot.

Currently, I have the following code:

```python
from numpy import loadtxt,array,asarray,append,std,median,empty,take

data = loadtxt(infile,usecols=(0,1,2))
mag = data1[:,2].tolist() 
dmag = data1[:,3].tolist() 
expnum = data1[:,4].tolist() 

#initialize variables
indexing = list() 
master_mag = list() 
master_dmag = list() 
sub_mag = list() 
sub_dmag = list() 

mag_std = array([]) 
mag_stdmed = array([]) 
mag_med = array([])  

while len(mag) > 0: 
    num=expnum[0] 
    for i in range(0,len(expnum)): 
        if expnum[i] == num: 
            sub_mag.append(mag[i]) 
            sub_dmag.append(dmag[i]) 
            indexing.append(i) 

    #add the sub lists to their master lists
    master_mag.append(sub_mag) 
    master_dmag.append(sub_dmag) 
    sub_mag=list() 
    sub_dmag=list()

    #remove from mag, dmag, and expnum the index referred to by indexing
    while len(indexing) > 0:    
        mag.pop(indexing[-1]) 
        dmag.pop(indexing[-1]) 
        expnum.pop(indexing[-1]) 
        indexing.pop() 

#make the master mag and dmag lists into numpy arrays 
master_mag=asarray(master_mag) 
master_dmag=asarray(master_dmag) 

#generate the mag and dmag median and mag std arrays 
for i in range(0,len(master_mag)): 
    mag_std=append(mag_std,std(master_mag[i])) 
    mag_med=append(mag_med,median(master_mag[i])) 
    mag_stdmed=append(mag_stdmed,median(master_dmag[i])) 

#create empty numpy arrays to be used for mag med vs. mag std 
#and mag med vs. dmag med 
med_std=empty([0,2]) 
med_dmed=empty([0,2]) 

#fill in those arrays 
for i in range(0,len(mag_std)): 
    med_std=append(med_std,[[mag_med[i],mag_std[i]]],axis=0) 
    med_dmed=append(med_dmed,[[mag_med[i],mag_stdmed[i]]],axis=0) 

#sort the median mag and dmag standard deviation arrays by median mag 
order_med_std=med_std[:,0].argsort() 
order_med_dmed=med_dmed[:,0].argsort() 

sorted_med_std=take(med_std,order_med_std,0) 
sorted_med_dmed=take(med_dmed,order_med_dmed,0)
```

And then I'm ready to plot `sorted_med_dmed[:,0]` vs. `sorted_med_dmed[:,1]` and `sorted_med_std[:,0]` vs. `sorted_med_std[:,1]`

This code works, it's just that I feel that it is too slow (especially when I get over 10,000 data points to work with). I want to try and vectorize this code to make it much quicker, but I have no idea where to begin.

I would like some help figuring out how to vectorize the matching-by-exposure-number component. I was thinking of creating a multi-dimensional array at the start that has the format: `array([[[mag],[dmag]],...])` and a length equal to the number of different exposure numbers. Is there a way to generate and update an array like this in-line, without having to use a ton of loops?

Please let me know if you need any further clarity on what exactly this code is doing.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a hard to work out exactly what calculations you are trying to perform. If you were to write down in equation form med_dmed=..., then chances are that the appropriate numpy expression would be very similar.

Comment: @Iggy I think you need to explain more what exactly you are trying to do. There is a better way of doing loop with the faster performance and you can optimize the speed of your code by using `multiprocessing`. You can look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing/5550156#5550156) and figure out how you can re-write your code in this frame.

Answer (score 2):

First step in any problem like this should always be profiling. I recommend trying [line_profiler](https://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/), because it makes it easy to find hotspots visually. (You can also try Python's built-in profiler, but I find its output harder to parse.)

That should give you an idea of which parts are slowing your code down the most. Without trying it myself, I can offer a few bits of advice:

- Try to avoid using Python lists when numpy arrays will suffice. Lists are fast if you're doing lots of `append`s, but slow for most other operations, and they don't support vectorization.
- Relatedly, try to avoid calling `numpy.append` if you can. Each call involves allocating more memory and copying, which can be quite slow in a loop.
- Use dictionaries to group data by keys. I find the stdlib `collections.defaultdict` quite useful for grouping like this:

  ```
  groups = defaultdict(list)
  for a,b,key in data:
    groups[key].append((a,b))
  ```
- Use numpy's auto-vectorized function calls instead of calling functions in a loop. For example, this code:

  ```
  #generate the mag and dmag median and mag std arrays 
  for i in range(0,len(master_mag)): 
    mag_std=append(mag_std,std(master_mag[i])) 
    mag_med=append(mag_med,median(master_mag[i])) 
    mag_stdmed=append(mag_stdmed,median(master_dmag[i]))
  ```

  will be much faster when written as:

  ```
  mag_std = numpy.std(master_mag, axis=0)
  mag_meg = numpy.median(master_mag, axis=0)
  mag_stdmed = numpy.median(master_dmag, axis=0)
  ```