# How to modify different parts of a numpy array of complex numbers in parallel using python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, scipy

How to modify different parts of a numpy array of complex numbers in parallel using python?
This question seems to give an answer for numpy array with real coefficients: [Is shared readonly data copied to different processes for Python multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing) , but not for complex coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You need to view the array containing twice the number of floats floats as complex numbers:

```
>>> shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, 3*3*2)
>>> shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())
>>> shared_array = shared_array.view(np.complex128).reshape(3, 3)
```

The complex number format is [re0, im0, re1, im1, re2, im2, ...]:

```
>>> shared_array[1,1] = 1+2j
>>> shared_array.base
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> shared_array.base.base
<multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_18 object at 0x7f7c1b5d1f80>
```