# How to use pandas DataFrame in shared memory during multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

In [one answer to: Is shared readonly data copied to different processes for multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5550156/9098935) a working solution for shared memory for a numpy array is given.

How would the same look like if a pandas DataFrame should be used?

Background: I would like to be able to write to the DataFrame during multiprocessing and would like to be able to process it further after the multiprocessing has finished.

Comment: Have you considered using dask?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I would like to add new rows to the Dataframe with ʼdf.loc[len(df)] = [x, x]ʼ. Would dask help me with this easily and take care that this happens in a synchronized way?

Comment: Do you mean preserving order?

Comment: You might want to have a look as this toy example [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0y9RfXaW)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use dask, you can share a pandas dataframe using shared memory by first converting it to a numpy array and then reconstructing it in the child processes.

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

def create_shared_block(to_share, dtypes):
    # float64 can't be pickled
    for col, dtype in to_share.dtypes.items():
        if dtype == 'float64':
            to_share[col] = pd.to_numeric(to_share[col], downcast='float')
            
    # make the dataframe a numpy array
    to_share.reset_index(inplace=True)
    
    # drop the index if named index
    to_share = to_share.drop('index', axis=1)
    
    # get the dtypes in the same order as the dataframe columns and make sure the types are correct for numpy
    dtypes_sorted = sort_dtypes(to_share, dtypes)
    
    # get the dataframe values in the format expected by numpy
    values = [tuple(x) for x in to_share.values.tolist()]
    
    # create a numpy array
    to_share = np.array(values, dtype=(dtypes_sorted))
    
    # create a shared memory of the size of the array
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=to_share.nbytes)
    
    # now create a NumPy array backed by shared memory
    np_array = np.ndarray(to_share.shape, dtype=dtypes_sorted, buffer=shm.buf)
    
    # Copy the original data into shared memory
    np_array[:] = to_share[:]
    return shm, np_array, dtypes_sorted


def sort_dtypes(df, dtypes):
    # category is a pandas dtype, not numpy
    string_types = ('category', 'object', '|S')
    dtypes = [(x, '|S{}'.format(df[x].str.len().max())) if y in string_types else (x, y) for x, y in dtypes if
              x in df.columns]
    # build a lookup
    dtypes_dict = {x: y for x, y in dtypes}
    # fix the order
    dtypes_sorted = [(x, dtypes_dict[x]) for x in df.columns]
    return dtypes_sorted

# ------PARENT PROCESS-------#
# create your shared memory
to_share = pd.DataFrame([['obstacle','obstacle',2,3],['obstacles','obstacle',2,np.nan]],columns=['w1','w2','d1','d2'])
dtypes = [('w1','str'),('w2','|S'),('d1','f'),('d2','f')]
shm, arr, dtypes_sorted = create_shared_block(to_share, dtypes)

# then pass these values to your child processes
shared = (shm.name, arr.shape, dtypes_sorted)

# ------CHILD PROCESS-------#
# assuming you have passed to the child process in a variable called shared, you can reconstruct the dataframe as follows
shared_memory = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shared[0])
np_array = np.ndarray(shared[1], dtype=shared[2], buffer=shared_memory.buf)
columns = [x for x, y in shared[2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array, columns=columns)
```

This has saved some memory in my app when sharing a 100k row dataframe but probably not as much as I could save using some established library like dask. And I'm not too sure of the overhead involved in recreating the pandas dataframe - I'd like to think it just references the shared numpy array and adds some extra stuff on top to make it a df.

Comment: >=Python 3.8 only

Comment: I'm looking for a straightforward solution to pass a DF into shared memory across multiple processes. I understand what's happening here, but is there any way of passing in the DF without reconstructing it from a numpy array?  This seems like a huge amount of code for something that's surely quite common.  Especially, if you don't know the layout of the dataframe, thus relying on lots of iterations and conditional logic.

Comment: AFAIK, you should just use [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) or [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/) instead of trying to create your own solution using shared memory. I didn't want to learn another library when I wrote this. However, I probably spent more time figuring out how to pass the df around than I would've learning Dask/Polars.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(np_array, columns=columns)
Seems it is doing a copy, I have used Line Profiler, and this takes quite a long time(for ~300MB data needs 500ms)

Comment: It's a while ago, but, when I used this approach I was able to share a large dataframe [many times](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/5051#discussioncomment-187119) without maxing out my RAM.