# How to use dask to populate DataFrame in parallelized task?

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, dask

I would like to use dask to parallelize a numbercrunching task.

This task utilizes only one of the cores in my computer.

As a result of that task I would like to add an entry to a DataFrame via `shared_df.loc[len(shared_df)] = [x, 'y']`. This DataFrame should be populized by all the (four) paralllel workers / threads in my computer.

How do I have to setup dask to perform this?

Comment: It looks to me the same question you asked on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320422/how-to-use-pandas-dataframe-in-shared-memory-during-multiprocessing?noredirect=1#comment93542449_53320422)
Have a look to my comment for a toy example. Otherwise please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this particular problem. It's not clear to me what  `[x, 'y']` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do something like this, in rough outline:

- make a function that, for a given argument, returns a data-frame of some part of the total data
- wrap this function in `dask.delayed`, make a list of calls for each input argument, and make a dask-dataframe with `dd.from_delayed`
- if you really need the index to be sorted and the index to partition along different lines than the chunking you applied in the previous step, you may want to do `set_index`

Please read the docstrings and examples for each of these steps!