# Dataframe memoryview

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to share the memory/data contained in a dataframe with another item? I naively tried this using `memoryview`, but I think it's quite a bit more complex than this (or possibly not supported at all):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([{'Name':'Brad'}])
>>> v=memoryview(df)
```

> TypeError: cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface

Comment: Why exactly do you need to share memory? If you are not mutating the dataframe, you can just copy the reference to it `df2 = df` or use `df2 = df.copy(deep=True)` if you want to completely copy the data or with `deep=False` to make a shallow copy. If you are memory constrained, you might want to look at loading data in chunks or using a library like `dask.frame`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62781869/1453508) help?