# Python Multiprocessing starmap

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i am trying to run a function in parallel with `Multiprocessing starmap`.

```
data = [(i, board) for i in range(board.width)]
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            p = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
            ratings = p.starmap(self.rate, data)
            print("Ratings: " + ratings)
```

My problem is that `print` is never executed. The Function just returns with None. 
`self.rate()` should return a number.

Github: https://github.com/Builder20/Connect4/tree/develop

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the definition of `self.rate`?

Comment: and what is board?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious the function loops. you can add logging to see which parts loops, I see the only candidate.

```
         while canSet == -1:
            opponentColumn = random.randint(0, board.width)
            canSet = board.setStone(self.other, opponentColumn)
```

add

```
logging.info(board)
```

to see how it progresses

Comment: It is calling itself until state is 3 then it should a result.

Comment: Did not read the code, but you probably wrongly assume that processes can share an object

Comment: Maybe, this is my first try with Multiprocessing in Python. So you think it cannot interact/reach board?

Comment: Ok. So my problem is that I try to use board as shared resource and I need to get one Instance per process?

Comment: Not sure is it the only issues. btw there are ways to share data between threads https://stackoverflow.com/a/5550156/5874981 https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html