# Why Python shared memory requires a copy?

Tags: python, numpy, shared-memory

I was trying to build a simple example of new Python [SharedMemory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) class by amending a shared numpy array. I`ve seen a few examples on the web here:

[Shared memory in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/shared-memory-in-multiprocessing)

[Is shared readonly data copied to different processes for multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-multiprocessing/5550156#5550156)

However all of them change the shared array inside the `__main__` block for some reason and then just print it. However, I would like to **return** a shared array from the function and reuse it later. Here is my try:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np


def create_shared_array():
    # instantiate array
    np_array = np.ones((5, 2, 2))
    # instantiate shared array
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(size=np_array.nbytes, create=True)
    # copy data from original array into shared array
    array_shared = np.ndarray(np_array.shape, dtype=np_array.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    array_shared[:] = np_array[:]
    return shm


def change_and_return(name):
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=name, create=False)
    array_shared = np.ndarray((5, 2, 2), dtype=np.float64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    # change shared array
    array_shared[0] = 888
    return array_shared


shm = create_shared_array()
result = change_and_return(shm.name)
print(result)
```

For some reason this code returns `"The instruction at <memory address> referenced memory at <another address>. The memory could not be read."` on my Windows machine.

However, if I just replace this

```
return array_shared
```

with this

```
return array_shared.copy()
```

Then it works just fine.

**My thoughts:**

Since `change_and_return` does not return `existing_shm` then it gets garbage collected and `array_shared` is destroyed as well. However, I do make sure not to kill `shm` so the reference should still exist ?

**Question**: why an additional copy is required and what is the right way here to avoid making an additional copy ?

**UPDATE**: let me be clear here - I would like to change array values in shared memory but *after that* I would like to use it in a non-shared fashion. Just like a regular numpy array. So the question is basically if it is possible to turn a shared array back into non-shared one without copying ?

Comment: "Then it works just fine." - no it doesn't. The copy isn't backed by shared memory.

Comment: The code works for me in this case - does it break for you ?

Comment: It runs without raising an exception, but it doesn't actually work - it fails silently, doing something completely different from what you intended. Again, the copy isn't backed by shared memory.

Comment: "No exception" and "works" are very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy is **wrong**. It makes an array backed by **non-shared memory**, completely defeating the point of what you're doing.

You say that

> However, I do make sure not to kill `shm`

but that's not true. You do nothing to keep `shm` alive. It dies, and its [`__del__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py#L182) calls `close`, and the memory is no longer accessible.

You need to retain a reference to `shm` to make sure the memory is still accessible. Additionally, for proper cleanup, each process should call `shm.close()` after it no longer needs to use the shared memory, and a single process should call `shm.unlink()` after all processes have called `close`. Otherwise, you risk leaking the memory **even after your program has terminated**. (On Unix, Python spawns a [server process](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py) to try to protect against this, but it's not completely reliable, and even when it works, it'll perform cleanup late.)

Comment: Sorry but if I do shm.close(), existing_shm.close() after I call both functions then memory error will happen as well. What is the right way to use array_shared and not pair it every time with the corresponding SharedMemory class instance ?

Comment: @Kreol: You need to call it **after you no longer need the shared memory**. You're calling it while you still need the memory.

Comment: "What is the right way to use array_shared and not pair it every time with the corresponding SharedMemory class instance ?" - there is no right way to do that. You need to keep the SharedMemory object around.

Comment: I do not need array_shared to be "shared" after I have done transforms to it in other processes. I just would like to keep using this numpy array in my main process. I guess your point is that in this case I have to make another copy ?

Comment: @Kreol: Then stop using shared memory! Why are you using shared memory if you don't want it to be shared?

Comment: As I said, I just would like to make changes to the array using shared memory. But I do not need shared memory AFTER I made changes. Just the array itself

Comment: @Kreol: Then go ahead and make a non-shared copy, but remember to clean up the shared memory.