# How do ShareableLists actually work when multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, shared-memory

What I want to acchieve is, that a list with 10 to 20 thousand dicts inside is used in parallel. For that I am using multiprocessing. The problem with that is, that each process was using something between 2-4 GBs of RAM. After some research I have found the `ShareableList` object from which I though would resolve in the processes sharing the same resources instead of copying gigabytes of data for themselves.

I have been testing with following code:

```py
## main.ipynb
# Test shared mem
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from utils import mult

with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
    sl = smm.ShareableList(range(2000))
    with Pool(processes=3) as p:
        with tqdm(total=len(sl), desc="Going through articles") as pbar:
            for res in p.imap_unordered(mult, sl, chunksize=100):
                pbar.update()
total_result = sum(sl)
total_result
```

```py
## utils.py
def mult(x):
    return x**2
```

I would expect, that each process only takes someting like 100MB, but after some testing even when using a `ShareableList`, every single one takes up 2-3 GB.

Here are some numbers for reverence. When running this code inside VSCode I got following peak RAM usages (in [GB]):

- Idle: 7
- 1 Process(es): 10
- 2 Process(es): 12,7
- 3 Process(es): 15,1

I have also tried another solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34614019) with an identical result.

Note: I am importing the mult function because multiprocessing in Notebook kind of only works that way rn. If the mult function is defined in the same cell, then the processes never seem to start.

PS: Using Python 3.11.0 in venv and ipynb file inside VSCode